# Inside an If statement how to perform only certain actions.

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, int

Basically I have an array with a length of 6. This array is used in a simple for loop. Within the for loop I have an if statement. The problem is, if the condition in the if statement is met, all of the contents off the if statement are obviously performed. This is not what I want.

I need if, for example, the 2nd and 4th element of the array only pass the condition then only for "arrayp2" and "arrayp4" to be performed.

Any help would be amazing. Thanks in advance!

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    if (array[i] >= 100)
    {
        arrayp1.someMethod(Action);
        arrayp2.someMethod(Action);                 
        arrayp3.someMethod(Action);             
        arrayp4.someMethod(Action);             
        arrayp5.someMethod(Action);                     
        arrayp6.someMethod(Action);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand but are you asking how to implement a conditional action in your code, inside an `if` statement ?

Comment: `"I need if, for example, the 2nd and 4th element of the array only pass the condition then only for "arrayp2" and "arrayp4" to be performed."` - What does that even mean?

Comment: I mean if say only the 3rd element of the array passes the if statement, then only "arrayp3.someMethod(Action);" must be executed. If the 5th and 6th elements of the array pass the if statement, then only "arrayp5.someMethod(Action);" and "arrayp6.someMethod(Action);" must be executed. You understand? And thanks for the help! - And its Java.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a switch Statment.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= array.length; i++)
{
    switch(i){
         case 1: if (array[i - 1] >= 100) arrayp1.someMethod(Action); break; 
         case 2: if (array[i - 1] >= 100) arrayp2.someMethod(Action); break; 
         case 3: if (array[i - 1] >= 100) arrayp3.someMethod(Action); break; 
         case 4: if (array[i - 1] >= 100) arrayp4.someMethod(Action); break; 
         case 5: if (array[i - 1] >= 100) arrayp5.someMethod(Action); break; 
         case 6: if (array[i - 1] >= 100) arrayp6.someMethod(Action); break; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean if say only the 3rd element of the array passes the if statement, then only "arrayp3.someMethod(Action);" must be executed. If the 5th and 6th elements of the array pass the if statement, then only "arrayp5.someMethod(Action);" and "arrayp6.someMethod(Action);" must be executed. You understand? And thanks for the help! - And its Java.

Comment: What is the condition? To be more than 100? And how many elements are there, 6?

Comment: 6 elements and its just I only want the corresponding line inside the if to be ran depending on the number of the element.

Comment: See my edit. I think you want a switch statement for `i`. But start `i` at 1.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 if statements where only 1 is needed. Your first if statement should do the trick already.

```
if(array[i] >= 100){
      system.out.println("hello world");
   }
```

The for loop iterates through all the value's of the array, when the condition is met, the if statement will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Place arrayp1, arrayp2, ... , arrayp6 also in a array A

In the if you can then access them with: `A[i].someMethod(Action)`